# Texmaker 5.0.2 shows Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: texmaker

As per title I open a file and try to quick build it but I get:
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

The same error happens with texstudio.

Reading on stack I understood that it has to do with the configuration in "configure texmaker" (I currently have: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex) however I am unable to understand what I have to put there in order to fix this issue.

I am on Lubuntu 18.04

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give a few more details as from what you have said it is not possible to help. As a start please add the error message to your post, your operating system, your tex installation and anything else that you think may be relevant.

Comment: have you installed tex? what happens if you type `pdflatex` at the commandline?